# Looking for basics of reading audio frequencies in C

Tags: c, signal-processing

I don't want to use libraries- I want to write from scratch.  I want to play around making a decoder for WEFAX transmitted over the radio.  Different audio frequencies convert to different pixel darknesses.  Gray scales only - no color.

There are 120 lines per minute each with somewhere over 1000 pixels.  I want to detect the frequency and turn it into probably an 8 bit value.  The hardware equivalent would be something like an LM567 frequency to voltage converter.

I haven't any idea where to start.  Is this something like an FIR or IIR?  Can anyone point me to code I can study?  I'm not writing for Windows, strictly unix.

Alan

Comment: Look up `Frequency Estimation`, `Pitch Detection` and `(Fast) Discrete Fourier Transform`.

Comment: Have a look at [Aquila](http://aquila-dsp.org/) or [aubio](http://aubio.org/). (Even if you want to write from scratch, you should look at how other people have done it if you have no idea how to even get started.)

Answer (score 1):

you could do it just with a timer and zero crossing to find out the fundamental frequency

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_crossing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have IQ data, you could start with a simple FM demodulator implemented with a phase differentiator.  Frequency is the derivative of phase, so you can simply calculate the phase difference from sample to sample to get an estimate of the original FM signal.  A single output sample may be given by something like:

```
y[k] = arctan(imag(x[k]) / real(x[k])) - arctan(imag(x[k-1]) / real(x[k-1]))
```

You also may need to perform some phase unwrapping to avoid jumps in the output by multiples of `2*pi`.  See the instantaneous frequency section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase) for more details.

The output of the FM demod should basically be your image since it will produce a signal that varies in amplitude in the way the original signal varied in frequency.  You will have to resample it to the correct pixel grid and scale/quantize the gray levels correctly.

It may improve the image quality to lowpass filter the output of the FM demodulator to reduce noise as well.